# Corrected: Solve[] cannot solve simple hyperbola equations?

Tags: equation-solving

Is Solve[] very inefficient in solving equations involving square roots?

The input below attempts to find out the explicit expression of either x or y in terms of other variables {x|y, a, c}, and c is the focal length, a is directrix.

F = (Sqrt[(x+c)^2+y^2]-Sqrt[(x-c)^2+y^2]==2a && x>0 && c>0 && a>0 && c>a)

Solve[F,y]

Solve[F,x]

After running on my Acer dual core laptop for over 4 hours this input is still shown in “running” state.

http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Solve.html

“Solve deals primarily with linear and polynomial equations.”

So is the equation above an example that Solve[] works not so well with equations involving square roots (and likely other order roots) ?

Answer (score 4):

In this case, the main issue is that we should restrict the domain of `x` and `y` to be in the real numbers. Therefore, use the following:

```
Reduce[F, y, Reals]

(*
==> x > 0 && 0 < a <= x && 
 c > a && (y == -Sqrt[((a^4 - a^2 c^2 - a^2 x^2 + c^2 x^2)/a^2)] || 
   y == Sqrt[(a^4 - a^2 c^2 - a^2 x^2 + c^2 x^2)/a^2])
*)

Reduce[F, x, Reals]

(*
==> c > 0 && 0 < a < c && 
 x == Sqrt[(a^4 - a^2 c^2 - a^2 y^2)/(a^2 - c^2)]
*)
```

It's done in the blink of an eye.

If you prefer, `Solve` can also do it but gives a different formulation of the answer:

```
Solve[F, y, Reals]

(*
==> {{y -> 
   ConditionalExpression[-Sqrt[((a^4 - a^2 c^2 - a^2 x^2 + c^2 x^2)/
     a^2)], 0 < a < x && c > a && x > 0]}, {y -> 
   ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[(a^4 - a^2 c^2 - a^2 x^2 + c^2 x^2)/
    a^2], 0 < a < x && c > a && x > 0]}}
*)

Solve[F, x, Reals]

(*
==> {{x -> 
   ConditionalExpression[Sqrt[(a^4 - a^2 c^2 - a^2 y^2)/(
    a^2 - c^2)], (0 < a < c && c > 0 && y > 0) || (0 < a < c && 
       y < 0 && c > 0)]}}
*)
```

Comment: (Sqrt[(x+a)^2+y^2]-Sqrt[(x-a)^2+y^2]==c&&c>0&&a>0&&c>2a)


-Sqrt[(-a+x)^2+y^2]+Sqrt[(a+x)^2+y^2]==c&&c>0&&a>0&&c>2 a


Solve[%,x,Reals]


{}


Reduce[%%,x,Reals]


False




Thanks very much for your help. I did try your solution , however it worked only ONCE and gave the correct result in "ConditionalExpression"; in all subsequent runnings I got the above.

Comment: Reduce[] returns false, and Solve[] returns empty set. I cannot find an apparent error that has caused the failure. The link for the failed notebook file "hyperbola.nb" is [here](http://wikisend.com/download/666536/hyperbola.nb)

Comment: Dear @Jimmy, please do not use answers to post comments to answers; if the comment box is too small, you might consider splitting into two comments, or shortening what you've written.

Comment: Thanks for doing the conversion.

Comment: You must have made a mistake, but I can only guess what it is because your syntax is wrong again. Do not use `%` in `Solve`, use a name for the equation to be solved and refer to that name in `Solve`.

Comment: Indeed it was a mistake in the equation itself. 

If we use 

Solve[Sqrt[(x + c)^2 + y^2] - Sqrt[(x - c)^2 + y^2] == 2 a && c > 0 &&   a > 0 && c > a, y,   Reals] // FullSimplify

This is solved immediately. The mistakes were at the right part following the == symbol, should be ==2a